# How can I find last time an azure function was executed in log analytics workspace?

Tags: kql, azure-log-analytics

Trying to find the last execution time for all my functions in log analytics

I wrote this simple query to start

```
AppRequests
| distinct OperationName
| take 10
```

But how Can I get the last executionTime? I tried adding TimeGenerated which would also work

I would like the final result to be:

```
OperationName, LastExecutionTime
Function1      2022-01-01 
Function2      2021-05-05
```

And so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[summarize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/summarizeoperator) operator

```
AppRequests
| summarize max(LastExecutionTime) by OperationName
```